# Using ASP.NET with GridView , which Wrapped itself with no reason

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

So here is my situation：
[situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHwEj.png)

These GridView is writed by same structure in aspx or aspx.cs , but IDK why the first GridView generate as two  . It happened after I upgrade my jquery to 3.7.1.

BTW , Because some reson I cant share this project file on net , Sorry.

"OurBook"

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvQueryData_OURBOOK_0" runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BATCH_NUM" Width="100%"
OnPageIndexChanging="gvQueryData_OURBOOK_0_PageIndexChanging"
OnRowDataBound="gvQueryData_OURBOOK_0_RowDataBound" AllowSorting="True"
OnSorting="gvQueryData_OURBOOK_0_Sorting" CssClass="GridViewHeader"
EmptyDataText="該查詢條件無符合資料。">
  <EditRowStyle Font-Italic="False" />
  <EmptyDataRowStyle BackColor="#DBEBF5" />
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003366" Height="27px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7E7" ForeColor="#003366" Height="27px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#DBEBF5" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="#003366" Height="35px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#DBEBF5" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="#003366" Font-Size="Larger" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <Columns>
  ...
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

"THBook"

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvQueryData_THBOOK_0" runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BATCH_NUM" Width="100%"
OnPageIndexChanging="gvQueryData_THBOOK_0_PageIndexChanging"
OnRowDataBound="gvQueryData_THBOOK_0_RowDataBound" AllowSorting="True"
OnSorting="gvQueryData_THBOOK_0_Sorting" CssClass="GridViewHeader"
EmptyDataText="該查詢條件無符合資料。">
  <EmptyDataRowStyle BackColor="#DBEBF5" />
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003366" Height="27px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7E7" ForeColor="#003366" Height="27px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#DBEBF5" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="#003366" Height="35px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#DBEBF5" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="#003366" Font-Size="Larger" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <Columns>
  ...
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And I checked every .cs which may cause this problem , but ALL "OurBook" and "THBook" is same structure , I think this problem is caused by GridViewScroll.min.js , but IDK how to solve it .

Sincere Thanks  , By English noob

**Problem is solved.**

Just update GridViewSrcoll.js , that's all.